# Using SSI in HTMLs imported using c:import in jsps

Tags: html, jsp, ssi

I have a bunch of htmls in the webserver context (outside the application context) in the htdocs area. These htmls use SSI to call other htmls.

Here's the problem:
When I use c:import to call the main html into the jsp, the secondary htmls inside the main html don't render / are not processed.

Is there a way to get the main html to "compile" and then return to the jsp?

JSP codes:

```
<c:import url="<%=/folder/Header.html%>"
```

HTML server side logic that needs to be processed:

```
<!--#include virtual="/abc/xyz.html" -->
<!--#if expr='"$Category" = "someCategory"' -->
<!--#echo var="pageTitle" -->
```

The prototypes were given as all htmls, so everything was in the web context and all files worked fine. The issue is moving the top layer to JSP and keeping the rest of the layers as HTML. (Its a requirement)

Any solutions /thoughts/ ideas would be welcome! Thanks for your asssistance!

Wave

EDIT: Ok, I'm getting the Header.html in an iFrame because that will initiate a new HTTP request (and thus have access to the SSI logic).

```
<iframe id="testSSI" src ="http://somesite.com/subfolder/testssi_1.html?pageTitle=Applications" frameborder="0" width="800px" height="300"></iframe>
```

The parameters are sent in the URL and I've managed to extract the control parameters using js.

My query has reduced to this:
How can I access this js value "Applications" in the SSI logic? Is it possible to set is as an environment variable? That could be pulled by the SSI logic.. I realise that the Js will run after the SSI is done, but hoping someone here would be able to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, got it done.

I accessed the parameter in SSI by using the QUERY_STRING environment variable.
Example of html call:

```
http://somesite.com/subfolder/testssi_1.html?Applications
```

Example of how i retrieved the value:

```
<!--#set var="pageTitle" value="$QUERY_STRING" -->
<!--#if expr=" ${pageTitle} = Program "  -->
  do something
<!--#else -->
  do something else
<!--#endif -->
```

The objective here:
We use a JAVA framework. But Marketing wanted content to be editable by them in a separate process.This way, they can change the content frequently with out the intervention on the jsp / java team. (Eg. change header look and feel, add new links, etc)

Hope this helps someone out later. :)

Wave

Edit: In the example above -> "Applications" will take the logic to the else section..
In addition, to send name value pairs:

```
http://somesite.com/subfolder/testssi_1.html?name=Applications&app=Demo
```

you can reference them as:

```
<!--#if expr=" ${QUERY_STRING} = /name=Applications/ "  -->
```

AND

```
<!--#if expr=" ${QUERY_STRING} = /app=Demo/ "  -->
```